# babel core-js typed-array-constructor: Cannot find module '../internals/to-offset'

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I am getting this error when trying to use core-js:

```
typed-array-constructor.js:13 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '../internals/to-offset'
    at webpackMissingModule (typed-array-constructor.js:13)
```

I searched for the file in the node-modules/core-js package and it's there (twice: at core-js and core-js-pure packages.. there is also a core-js-compact that I don't know why it is there)
but when I check the browser debugger, it seems to be loading "core-js" and in the expected folder there is no evidence of the required file! should I import it by hand, or what I am missing here?

my .babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": [
     ["@babel/preset-env", {
      useBuiltIns: "usage", // or "entry"
      corejs: {           version: '3.6',           proposals: false       }
    }],
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": []
}
```

my index.js:

```
import 'core-js/stable';
import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime';
require('./app');
```

my webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/app.js', // relative path
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'), // absolute path
    filename: 'bundle.js' // file name
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

..and package json:

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "private": true,
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "watch": "webpack --watch",
    "build": "webpack",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --open",
    "assets": "cp -r ../assets ~/s3/local-medialibrary"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.10.1",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.19.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^1.7.0",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.5",
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.2",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.10.1",
    "@babel/runtime-corejs3": "^7.10.2",
    "ammo.js": "github:kripken/ammo.js",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "dat.gui": "^0.7.6",
    "pathfinding": "^0.4.18",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "stats.js": "^0.17.0",
    "three": "^0.114.0"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: humm.. I had not really found a solution, but a temporal workaround: if I commented out core-js from my index.js, it works. I understand that the function of core-js is to inject polyfills, so I am really interested in discover if some of these options is doable (and how):
1. keep core-js, but exclude typed-array polyfills..
2. force core-js to include those typed-array polyfills that seem mising from the bundle.

Comment: Apparently we're the only two people to ever encounter this issue.